# Why are root level attributes ignored for custom classes in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

Consider the following simple XAML:

```xml
<TextBlock x:Class="MyTextBlock"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
           Foreground="Red">
</TextBlock>
```

And the associated C# code:

```cs
public partial class MyTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    public MyTextBlock()
    {
    }
}
```

Why does the `Foreground="Red"` part not work when I then do `<MyTextBlock Text="Foo"/>` in my application? I know there are plenty of other ways to do it in code, but I have trouble understanding what is happening exactly here.

I have also tried the following XAML:

```xml
<TextBlock x:Class="MyTextBlock"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

And finally this one:

```xml
<TextBlock x:Class="MyTextBlock"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <TextBlock.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyTextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Resources>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <DynamicResource ResourceKey="MyTextBlockStyle"/>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Again, neither of these appear to apply the style. Why is that? Is there a way to declare some kind of default style for the root element in XAML?

Comment: A derived control (that is not a UserControl with an associated XAML file) typically has a default Style in `Themes\Generic.xaml`. You would have to set the DefaultStyleKey property in its code behind, preferably by overriding the default value of that property. See [Control authoring overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), it is a bit lengthy, but covers everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the Foreground="Red" part not work when I then do `<MyTextBlock Text="Foo"/>` in my application?

It works if you call `InitializeComponent()`:

```
public partial class MyTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    public MyTextBlock()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Local values take [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) over `Style` setters.